# Does letter casing of directories and urls matter in .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, directory, uppercase, lowercase

Say I have a TitleCase directory name, but call an item within that directory using a lowercase url.

Does that have any effect or impact?

For example, does the server need to do a redirect from the incorrect lettercase to the correct lettercase?

**Example**

A file here: `/PlugIns/CMSPages/Images/my-image.jpg`

Called with: `/plugins/cmspages/images/my-image.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing engine isn't case sensitive.

One thing to be wary of, if you are referring to page urls - Google treats lowercase and uppercase urls as different pages, so you want to make use of rel="canonical" to ensure Google  and other search engines know it is one page, no matter whether the url is upper or lowercase.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Does the case insensitive routing mean that there is absolutely no difference whatsoever in calling each of the urls above?